# Spark and AWS Kinesis

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to connect to Kinesis with Apache Spark 2.4.0 in standalone mode. I`m providing my credentials with below method:

```
val cred =  SparkAWSCredentials.builder.basicCredentials("{awsAccessKeyId}", "{awsSecretAccessKey}").build()
```

and getting such error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.$init$(Lorg/apache/spark/internal/Logging;)V
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.BasicCredentials.(SparkAWSCredentials.scala:51)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.SparkAWSCredentials$Builder.basicCredentials(SparkAWSCredentials.scala:116)
>       at $line18.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:34)
>       at $line18.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:39)
>       at $line18.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:41)
>       at $line18.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:43)
>       at $line18.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:45)
>       at $line18.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:47)
>       at $line18.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:49)
>       at $line18.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:51)
>       at $line18.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:53)
>       at $line18.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:55)
>       at $line18.$read$$iw$$iw.(:57)
>       at $line18.$read$$iw.(:59)
>       at $line18.$read.(:61)
>       at $line18.$read$.(:65)
>       at $line18.$read$.()
>       at $line18.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(:7)
>       at $line18.$eval$.$print(:6)
>       at $line18.$eval.$print()
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:793)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1054)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:645)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:644)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:644)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:576)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:572)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:819)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:691)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:404)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:425)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:285)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runClosure(SparkILoop.scala:159)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:182)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:78)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:58)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

When I`m trying to connect with credentials provided as enviroment variable or by setting them with:

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "{}")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey","{}")
```

I`m getting such error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)V
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.DefaultCredentials$.(SparkAWSCredentials.scala:39)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.DefaultCredentials$.(SparkAWSCredentials.scala)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisInputDStream$Builder.$anonfun$buildWithMessageHandler$6(KinesisInputDStream.scala:291)
>       at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisInputDStream$Builder.buildWithMessageHandler(KinesisInputDStream.scala:291)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisInputDStream$Builder.build(KinesisInputDStream.scala:302)
>       at $line24.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:43)
>       at $line24.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:48)
>       at $line24.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:50)
>       at $line24.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:52)
>       at $line24.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:54)
>       at $line24.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:56)
>       at $line24.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:58)
>       at $line24.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:60)
>       at $line24.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:62)
>       at $line24.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:64)
>       at $line24.$read$$iw$$iw.(:66)
>       at $line24.$read$$iw.(:68)
>       at $line24.$read.(:70)
>       at $line24.$read$.(:74)
>       at $line24.$read$.()
>       at $line24.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(:7)
>       at $line24.$eval$.$print(:6)
>       at $line24.$eval.$print()
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:793)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1054)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:645)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:644)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:644)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:576)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:572)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$20.apply(ILoop.scala:762)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$20.apply(ILoop.scala:762)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.withLabel(IMain.scala:116)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretCode$1(ILoop.scala:762)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.pasteCommand(ILoop.scala:776)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$standardCommands$9.apply(ILoop.scala:217)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$standardCommands$9.apply(ILoop.scala:217)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.LoopCommands$LineCmd.apply(LoopCommands.scala:62)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.colonCommand(ILoop.scala:698)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:689)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:404)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:425)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:285)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runClosure(SparkILoop.scala:159)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:182)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:78)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:58)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error, in my case I was using spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.12 instead of spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11.

Comment: thanks, changing to streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11 helped

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SparkAWSCredentials credentials = new SparkAWSCredentials.Builder().basicCredentials("***", "****").build();`

As per the scala code `Builder` is a class that can be accessed by using `SparkAWSCredentials` singleton.